# Synonyms have stopped working in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

All of a sudden I cannot get synonyms for tables working in BigQuery, so a query like the following works fine:

```
select id as id, value as value
from pos_dw_api.test
```

But a query like the following fails:

```
select a.id as id, a.value as value
from pos_dw_api.test a
```

The error returned is the following. I have run this from the web console:

```
Query Failed
Error: Unknown field: a.id
```

Synonyms were working just fine last week ... The example table I'm using for this select is `387047224813.pos_dw_api.test`.

Has the syntax for synonyms changed? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table synonyms generally only work when you're doing a JOIN. I don't know of anything that would have caused this to change. I realize that this is kind of strange, and I've filed an internal bug to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, that makes sense. The issue actually came up while doing a multiple JOIN query via the the inner sub-selects approach, where I had the inner-most query with synonyms, removing the synonyms from that inner-most query works fine.